# Sublime-Text Force to not load previous files

Tags: sublimetext3

I've accidentally opened tons of files. The nice feature that Sublime loads all files which were open in the previous session becomes a problem at this moment.

So i've find a setting to disable this feature, so that i start with a clean session.

**Prefrences/Settings/User**

```
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": false,
```

However this doesn't help. When i open SB3, still it loads all the files which were open before. Maybe the config changes are not picked because i am  killing the app instead of closing?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. Why do you have to kill Sublime?

Comment: have you tried deleting the `Session.sublime_session` file in Sublime's data\Local folder (on Windows it is `%AppData%\Sublime Text 3\Local`)?

Comment: @MattDMo because when i normally close it, it will ask me to close over 6000 Tabs and i don't want to click "close without saving" 6000 times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the easiest way around this will be to delete your `.sublime_session` files. They should be located in the following places:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local`
- Windows: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local`

(I can confirm the first two, but I don't have access to a Windows box at the moment to confirm the last location. I'm reasonably sure that's its location, through.)

Open the `Local` folder either via the command line or through your operating system's file manager (I'd recommend the command line for OS X and Linux as `~/Library` and `~/.config` are hidden by default). Make sure Sublime is closed, then delete `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` and `Session.sublime_session`. This will not only close all the windows and tabs you have open, but it will also remove the entries in the **`File -> Open Recent`** and **`Project -> Open Recent`** menus.

Comment: That worked great! Awesome Dude! I didn't have to delete Auto Save is this file wasn't there anymore when i'v killed sublime. Just got rid of Session.sublime_session

Comment: @user1767754 great, glad I could help!

Comment: I had persistent old sessions reloading of an old session in Windows 10, and it turned out that besides `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local`, Sublime was also storing them in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Local`

Answer (score -1):

The following hack will close everything but without losing the recent files. It works in Mac but not sure about other OS.

1. Right click and select Quit. Then the annoying "Do you want to save..." dialog box will appear.
2. Then use Force Quit and close the sublime.